# Fullscreen background with absolute divs

Tags: html

I'm trying to display a full screen background with multiple div's on top of it. When I'm resizing the browser, the divs also have to move. I want the divs to resize as well, so that they will stay at the same spot of the  background image.

I've found a great solution on Stackoverflow, but the image isn't a full screen background. I've tried to adjust it but it doesn't seems to work. Who can help me?

```css
.div-bg {
    height: 100vmin;
    width: 100vmin;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.cities {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
}
.cities.Delhi {
    position: absolute;
    top: 27%;
    left: 30%;
}
.cities.Bangalore {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85%;
    left: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-bg" style="background-image:url('https://image.ibb.co/f1qio5/insights_indiamap.jpg')">
  <div class="cities Delhi"></div>
  <div class="cities Bangalore"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change `.cities` `position` from `absolute` to `fixed`...and instead of using `vmin` for width and height...use `px` or `rem`

```css
.div-bg {
  background-image: url('https://image.ibb.co/f1qio5/insights_indiamap.jpg');
  height: 30rem;
  width: 30rem;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: auto;
}

.cities {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.cities.Delhi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27%;
  left: 30%;
}

.cities.Bangalore {
  position: absolute;
  top: 85%;
  left: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-bg">
  <div class="cities Delhi"></div>
  <div class="cities Bangalore"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I’ve to change the background to full screen. The divs are fine! What do I have to change to get a full screen background?

Comment: you mean full screen even if  the browser is resizing ?

Comment: Yes! And the divs have to stay at the same spot on the background image, even if I'm resizing the browser. Like in the example.

Comment: instead of using `vmin` for width and height...use `px` or  `rem`